# Error while refreshing a JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp, session

From what I can see when the checkbox page passes of parameters to the Proto page, which puts it in the portfolio object which is then used to check the value of the data and display the portfolio name ,and when the proto page refreshes the parameters arent passed again from the checkbox page and the portfolio object has a null value stored in it which gives a null pointer exception.

so if I store the parameter values once they're already passed from the checkbox page would that solve the problem ? And if so how can I go about it ?

Here is the code for proto page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<head>
<title>Live Data Tracking</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.wrapper {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1379px;
background-color: #cccccc
}

.header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color: #356aa0
}

.left1 {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 338px;
background-color: #ffffff
}

.left2 {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 337px;
background-color: #ffffff
}

.left3 {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 337px;
background-color: #ffffff
}

.right {
float: right;
width: 337px;
background-color: #ffffff
}

.footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color: #00457b
}

body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 90%;
background-color: #e7e7de
}
</style>

</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

<%
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> testList = new ArrayList(); 
portfolio = request.getParameterValues("portfolio");


try{

 OracleDataSource ds= new OracleDataSource();
 //javax.sql.DataSource ds = new javax.sql.DataSource();
 ds.setDriverType("thin");
 ds.setServerName("localhost");
 ds.setPortNumber(1521);
 ds.setDatabaseName("orcl");
 ds.setUser("system");
 ds.setPassword("amex1234");
 Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
 System.out.println("Connected Successfully");


        Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
        if (portfolio!=null)
        { 
            for(int i=0;i<portfolio.length;i++)
                testList.add(new ArrayList());
            //System.out.println(testList);

            for(int i=0; i<portfolio.length;i++)    
            { String temp="";
                ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select num FROM "+portfolio[i]+"_Test") ; //Put in SQl command and Table name here 
            while(resultset.next()){

                temp = resultset.getString(1);
                testList.get(i).add(temp);      
            }


                //System.out.println(testList);
            }

        }

} catch(SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
    %>

</script>

<body>

<%! String[] portfolio; %>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <center>
            <h4>Live Tracker</h4>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="left1">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
        <%  
  if (portfolio != null) 
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < portfolio.length; i++)  //i=portfolio length proxy
  {
     out.println ("<b>"+portfolio[i]+"<b>"); %>
        <br>
        <% }
  }
  else out.println ("<b>none<b>");
   %>
    </div>
    <div class="left2">
        <h3>Pre-Stage</h3>
   for (int j = 0; j < portfolio.length; j++)
   {     
    response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 2);
    //System.out.println(testList.get(j).size());
    if (testList.get(j).size()!=0){ %>
        Data is there <br>
        <%  } else { %>
        No data <br>
        <% } 
        }%>
    </div>
    <div class="left3">
        <h3>Stage</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Mirror</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Something Funny and Witty Here</div>
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This is the code for the checkbox page. Run via this page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<HTML>
<body>
<FORM method="POST" ACTION="Proto_1.jsp">
<center>
Select your portfolio(s): <br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td> 

    <input TYPE=checkbox name=portfolio VALUE=X>
</td>    
<td>    
    X 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
    <input TYPE=checkbox name=portfolio VALUE=Y>
</td>    
<td>    
    Y
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
    <input TYPE=checkbox name=portfolio VALUE=W>
</td>    

<td>    
    W
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
    <input TYPE=checkbox name=portfolio VALUE=V>
</td>    

<td>    
    V
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
    <input TYPE=checkbox name=portfolio VALUE=S>
</td>    

<td>    
    S
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br> <INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Submit">
</center>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why do you need auto reload?

Comment: Need to track the changes made in the data base

Comment: Why not use ajax then?

Comment: Havent really used it before, if you can  point me in the right direction, I'll be much obliged ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to resolve.

Option 1: Set the params into session. Instead of:

```
portfolio = request.getParameterValues("portfolio");
```

Try this:

```
String[] portfolio = null;
if(null == request.getParameter("submit")) { //page reload, true
    portfolio = (String[])session.getAttribute("portfolio");
} else {
    portfolio = request.getParameterValues("portfolio");
    session.setAttribute("portfolio", portfolio);
}
```

Option 2: Separate the view and business logic i.e. split your page into two. First jsp to get the `portfolio` from request and make frequent call to get the updated records from the second jsp. This approach requires `JavaScript`.

*View.jsp:* Make call to the Records.jsp frequently using `setInterval()`

```
<script>
var getRecords = function() {
  //  to do here
};

setInterval(getRecords, 2 * 1000); (in miliseconds)[every 2 sec]
</script>
```

*Records.jsp:* Generate dynamic html along with records

Answer (score 0):

You can save the checkbox data to the session via session.setAttribute("portfolio", portfolio). 
You can retrieve this and set the value back to the page via document.getElementById(id).value or via value={$sessionVariable} in jsp